# how to convert a string type entered through command line to time type in shell script?

Tags: bash

I have a requirmnt where I want to convert the time entered from command line i.e 08:00 (8 am) to time type in shell script so that I can compare it with unix time in shell script.

$date +"%R"
$10:33

When I typed date +"%R" I got unix time as 10:33.
I want to compare 10:33 with 08:00. May I know how to convert 08:00 to time type so that I can compare with 10:33 in a while loop.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Bash doesn't have a time type. Variables are strings, even the ones that are forced to behave like integers. Note that the `date` command is not PART OF bash, it's merely an external program that you call from bash. And bash has no [`scanf()`](https://man.freebsd.org/scanf) or [`strptime()`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=strptime&sektion=3). Please add more to your question. Sample input data, and the results you're hoping to get from them. An [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows us how you're planning to use this.

Comment: You need a different language, do you have `gawk`?  It has some time extensions.

Comment: Why not use `cron` with `crontab`, or even `at`?  Do you have `gawk`?